# what's the mearning of `sudog` in the channel struct in Go?

Tags: go

According to Golang source code:
A `sudog` is simply a goroutine that is waiting on an element. The `sudog` struct has these elements

```
type sudog struct{
   g *g
   isSelect bool
   next *sudog
   prev *sudog
   elem unsafe.Pointer //data element
   ...
}
```

I want to know what's the hidden meaning of `sudo`? what's it short for?

Comment: It's [probably](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-codereviews/c/rC9BLPFvkW8) a pun on `psuedo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general consensus is that a `sudog` is a pseudo-`G`, as it is used to keep a list of G's.  There is some discussion on https://golang.org/cl/20774.

Comment: I almost agree with you